# breezejs: AutoGeneratedKeyType is undefined

Tags: breeze

AutoGeneratedKeyType  is defined in breeze.debug.js. However, now that I'm using DataService, I now also have to include the file breeze.dataService.webApi.js

Now when I call the method saveChanges(), I get an error in this file on the line :

```
 if (e.entityType.autoGeneratedKeyType !== AutoGeneratedKeyType.None) {
```

in the method *prepareSaveBundle*

The error is "AutoGeneratedKeyType is undefined". It seems this enum is only known to the file breeze.debug.js. Could that be a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running from the zip on the Breeze site or directly from GitHub? The GitHub version is a work in progress and will have bugs.  The zips on the Breeze site are full releases.

There should never be a reason to include breeze.dataService.webApi.js unless you are using breeze.base.xxx.js.  Instead, just use breeze.js or breeze.min.js.  These are a bit larger but include all of the adapter libraries.

Comment: I use breeze.debug.js from the zip file. Don't I have to use dataServices.webApi.js since I'm using DataServie ? I have noticed that if I change the code to breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType, then it works. Is that what I should do in the dataServices.webApi.js and dataServices.odata.js files ?

Comment: ok, for some reasons I thought I had to include these files, but now it seems to work fine with just breeze.debug.js. I must have done something silly earlier on...

Comment: References to all Breeze classes need to be prefixed with a "breeze.".  Typically, we create 'aliases' at the top of each module to make the code less verbose. i.e. var AutogeneratedKeyType = breeze.AutogeneratedKeyType and then we just use the 'short' version.  If you don't do this then you will need to prefix all of your refs.